# Codeigniter 3 | Imagic add background color for uploaded image

Tags: codeigniter

I follow the Codeigniter 3 documentation  for [Image Manipulation Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html)

But I don't see here an option to add/change the background color of an image during upload.

Is it possible to change bg-color of an image with built  in library  CL3 Imagic or I need to use any third party library imagic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageMagic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is a php library which you can use easily with the Codeigniter 3 [Image Manipulation Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html). It doesn't have a functionality of changing the background color during uploading.

To achieve what you pretend, you could use the PHP function [imagefill()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) having a look at this [user contributed note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php#110186)